# C++ Best way to allow user to declare a struct object?

Tags: c++, struct, syntax

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct player
{
  string name;
  int money = 100;
  int wins = 0;
};

int main()
{
  string user;
  cin >> user;
  player user;
  user.name = user;
}
```

What is the proper syntax for this in C++? I'm trying to declare the object name as the one given by the user. How would you do this? Would a class be easier to do this? Any tips/advice is much appreciated!

Comment: You have two different variables called `user`...

Comment: You can't have `string user` and `player user` defined in the same scope.

Comment: I want to call the object the name the user inputs... Like if the user inputs "bob" I want it to be:

player bob;
But... I am unsure on how to do this.

Comment: You want the variable name in the source code to change to bob, or you want the `name` member of your `player` struct to be `bob`? Your immediate problem is that you have two variables called `user`. One is a `std::string`, the other is a `player`. I recommend changing the `std::string user` to `std::string username` to be more verbose.

Comment: What benefit do you hope to gain by giving a variable a name that is not known at compile time? Assigning the string to the `name` field is typically enough for most purposes.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I believe the OP is trying to re-create in C++ what would be [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP -- declare a variable of type `player` whose name is the value of `user` (which would correspond to `$$user` in PHP syntax). It's an example of how knowledge of one language can mislead you in another language.

Answer (score 3):

variables names are meaningless at runtime in compiled langages like c++. If you want to refer to a player using his or her provided username at runtime you need a datastructure that will remember the name as as string, like a hashtable or a map (I would recommend a map, those are easier to use) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Answer (score 0):

best is classes because of security
as by default ,
classes are private in nature but struct are public in nature

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class player
{
  public:
  string name;
  int money;
  int wins;

  public(string name){
  this->name = name;
  this->money = 100;
  this->wins = 0;
}

};

int main()
{
string user;
cin >> user;
player *user = new player(user);

}
```